# Split an utf-8 encoded string given a bytes offset (python 2.7)

Tags: python, arrays, byte

Having an utf-8 encoded string like this:

```
bar = "hello ｡◕‿‿◕｡"
```

and a bytes offset that tells me at which byte I have to split the string:

```
bytes_offset = 9
```

how can I split the bar string in two parts resulting in:

```
>>first_part 
'hello ｡' <---- #9 bytes 'hello \xef\xbd\xa1'
>>second_part 
'◕‿‿◕｡'
```

*In a nutshell*:
given a bytes offset, how can I transform it in the actual char index position of an utf-8 encoded string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 Python 2.x strings are basically byte strings.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

bar = "hello ｡◕‿‿◕｡"
assert(isinstance(bar, str))

first_part = bar[:9]
second_part = bar[9:]
print first_part
print second_part
```

Yields:

```
hello ｡
◕‿‿◕｡
```

Python 2.6 on OSX here but I expect the same from 2.7. If I split on 10 or 11 instead of 9, I get ? characters output implying that it broke the sequence of bytes in the middle of a multibyte character sequence; splitting on 12 moves the first "eyeball" to the first part of the string.

I have PYTHONIOENCODING set to utf8 in the terminal.

Comment: I think you mean `assert(isinstance(bar, str))` or `assert(type(bar) is str)`.

Comment: Sure. For some reason I can never remember the operand order for isinstance().

Answer (score 0):

Character offset is a number of characters before byte offset:

```
def byte_to_char_offset(b_string, b_offset, encoding='utf8'):
    return len(b_string[:b_offset].decode(encoding))
```